# odd connection error - JDBC cannot find database but psql can

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm seeing connection errors when connecting to a database using JDBC. However, I'm able to connect to the same database using psql. Here's my connect string:

```
"jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/sample?user=postgres&password=postgres&loglevel=2"
```

I see the following logs upon connect and then the PSQLException.

```
16:33:49.425 (1) PostgreSQL 9.1 JDBC4 (build 901)
16:33:49.431 (1) Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to 127.0.0.1:5432
16:33:49.443 (1)  FE=> StartupPacket(user=postgres, database=sample, client_encoding=UTF8, DateStyle=ISO, extra_float_digits=2)
16:33:49.448 (1)  <=BE AuthenticationReqMD5(salt=da8b7230)
16:33:49.449 (1)  FE=> Password(md5digest=md5dc7d3827e761b7b18f553d6bdd15fa21)
16:33:49.451 (1)  <=BE AuthenticationOk
16:33:49.467 (1)  <=BE ErrorMessage(FATAL: database "sample" does not exist)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "sample" does not exist
```

However, I'm able to connect fine with psql command

```
$ psql -U postgres sample
psql (9.1.4)
Type "help" for help.

sample=#
```

What else can I try to isolate the issue?

Comment: Does `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres sample` work?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? Try passing the user/pwd as parameters to the `DriverManager.getConnection()` and use postgresql url as `jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/sample?loglevel=2`

Comment: @A.H. Thanks for the tip. Found the issue. The server was running on a different port 5433.